# How do I get my form to submit using parsley.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I've gotten the validation to work and the message appear on submit, however the page doesn't seem to process the form/refresh. Otherwise I think I am good to go!

This my html:

```
<form  parsley-validate id="frmContact" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"                           method="POST">
<p>
<label for="yourName">name</label>
<input id="yourName" parsley-required="true" parsley-mincheck="2" parsley-focus="first"  type="text" name="name" class="required textArea" placeholder="Please enter your full name"/>
</p>

<p>
<label for="email" >Email</label> 
<input id="email" data-trigger="change" parsley-required="true" parsley-type="email"  type="email" name="email" class="textArea" placeholder="Please enter your email address"/>
</p>

<p>
<label for="comments">Comments</label> 
<textarea id="comments" data-trigger="change" required data-required="true" name="comments"  class="textArea" title="Message field!"/>
</textarea>
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" class="submit myButtons submitButton specificLink button button-block button-rounded button-large" name="submit" value="Submit" placeholder="">
</p>

<div id="results" class="results" style="text-align:center;">
<span>
<p class="success">Your message was sent succssfully!<br> I will be in touch as soon as I can.
</p>
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

js/jquery:

```
var dd= $.noConflict();

dd(function() { 
  dd(":text:first").focus();
    dd(".success").hide();
      dd('#frmContact').submit(function(e) { 
          e.preventDefault();
          if ( dd(this).parsley('validate') ) {
              dd.post("index.php",  dd(".success").show());       
          }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `dd(this).parsley('validate')` with `true` and `false` to eliminate `parsley.js` from the problem.

You may then notice that `e.preventDefault();` does not work as you want it to. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) for more details.

Try this instead of your code:

```
dd(function() { 
  dd(":text:first").focus();
  dd(".success").hide();
  dd('#frmContact').submit(function(e) { 
    if ( dd(this).parsley('validate')) {
      dd.post("index.php",  dd(".success").show());       
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PEdg/).